# Multidimensional Array Computation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to **compute the largest product amongst four adjacent numbers** (integers) in a 20x20 grid.

This is what I have so far...

```
/**
 * The maxProduct method is used to compute the largest product across four 
 * consecutive integers (either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally).
 * 
 * @param gridData    - A 20x20 array containing the integer values.
 * @return maxProduct - The largest product.
 */
private static int maxProduct(int[][] gridData)
{
    int maxProduct = 0;
    int currentProduct = 0;

    // Compute the products across the columns.
    for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < 17; column++)
        {
            currentProduct = gridData[row][column] 
                    * gridData[row][column + 1] * gridData[row][column + 2] 
                    * gridData[row][column + 3];

            if (currentProduct > maxProduct)
            {
                maxProduct = currentProduct;
            }

        }

    // Compute the products across the rows.
    for (int column = 0; column < 20; column++)
        for (int row = 0; row < 17; row++)
        {
            currentProduct = gridData[row][column]
                    * gridData[row + 1][column] * gridData[row + 2][column]
                    * gridData[row + 3][column];

            if (currentProduct > maxProduct)
            {
                maxProduct = currentProduct;
            }
        }

    // Compute the products across the right diagonals.
    for (int column = 0; column < 17; column++)
        for (int row = 0; row < 17; row++)
        {
            currentProduct = gridData[row][column]
                    * gridData[row + 1][column + 1]
                    * gridData[row + 2][column + 2]
                    * gridData[row + 3][column + 3];

            if (currentProduct > maxProduct)
            {
                maxProduct = currentProduct;
            }

        }


    // Compute the products across the left diagonals.
    for (int column = 19; column < 3; column--)
        for (int row = 0; row < 17; row++)
        {
            currentProduct = gridData[row][column]
                    * gridData[row + 1][column - 1]
                    * gridData[row + 2][column - 2]
                    * gridData[row + 3][column - 3]; 

            if (currentProduct > maxProduct)
            {
                maxProduct = currentProduct;
            }
        }

    return maxProduct;
}
```

I've copied this code over from another one of my projects (it happened to be a Connect 4 game that used an 8x8 grid). Apparently my code for the Connect 4 game didn't work. My left diagonals failed the test cases, and I'm positive I have fixed the issue within this method.

The functionality should be identical (as far as computing the products), yet I'm not finding the correct value.

**Where is my logic wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I see is with this line:

```
for (int column = 19; column < 3; column--)
```

This will be `false` to start with and the block is never executed.  You probably need

```
for (int column = 19; column >= 3; column--)
```

Use `>=` so that the last valid value of `column` is 3 (and so `column - 3` evaluates to `0` and you reach the left side).

Answer (score 2):

This cycle seems to be wrong: `column = 19; column < 3; column--` you will never execute a single iteration. Maybe you meant `column > 3`?

Comment: Heh, simple mistake. That fixed it. Thanks for catching that for me!

Comment: You should use `column >= 3`, so that you also check the case for columns 0-3.  If you use `column > 3`, then the last case will check for columns 1-4.

Comment: I integrated that fix, I was just overlooking the conditional dangit. Thanks guys!